# Subiterate over a tuple

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function in python that will take a variable amount of elements with 2 distinct elements that will separate the arguments in two tuples. For example I would like to make a call like:

```
foo('D1', d1n1, d1n2, ... , 'D2', d2n1, d2n2, ...)
```

Where d1n1 etc are of the same type and I would like to get the elements between 'D1' and 'D2' in a tuple and the elements from 'D2' onwards in another. but I'm a bit loss on how to do it. Any help would be appreciated :).

Comment: In what way would this be useful?

Comment: A dictionary would make your life so much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be implemented by accepting an unlimited number of arguments using [`*args`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists), and then splitting the args by the index of the second distinct element.

For example:

```
def foo(*args):
    ind = args.index('D2')
    lst1 = args[:ind]
    lst2 = args[ind:]
    print lst1
    print lst2


foo('D1', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'D2', 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
('D1', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
('D2', 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

---

Another way to implement it, is to require the user to separate the arguments respectively, when she calls the function (using named-arguments):

```
def foo(lst1, lst2):
    print lst1
    print lst2


foo(lst1=['D1', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], lst2=['D2', 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: Now imagine if there is a `D3` in there.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid pretty trivial addition I would say. You're welcome to post it as a separate question and ping me ;)

Comment: There is an arbitrary number of `Dx` and your solution only deals with one case. Granted, the entire premise of the question is strange (it sounds like the [x/y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid please read again: "a variable amount of elements with 2 distinct elements that will separate the arguments in two tuples"

Comment: Thanks, I was using args but didnt know how to split them, though I'll use [1:ind] and [ind+1:] since I dont want the strings :)!